# Replace matched text in PDF with hyperlinked text

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf, fpdf

I'd like to do a find/replace on a PDF: to replace all occurrences of a string with a `hyperlinked` version of that same string. The end result should be a new version of the PDF with the text hyperlinked.

I.e. Matched String -> [Matched String](http://#)

*Any thoughts on the best approach to tackle this problem?*

**Update:** The challenge I'm currently stumped on, is how to find the position (e.g. x/y coordinates) of a given string in a PDF.

Comment: How do you know what to link it to? str_replace, preg_replace.

Comment: str_replace and preg_replace will not work. FPDF is not HTML, you need to use `Cell`. `<a>` tags will not work.

Answer (score 0):

FPDF's documentation is very useful: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/

You can use [`Cell`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm) to set a link. You will have to split the larger body of text for every occurrence of the substrings you want to link. You will need to be very conscious of the `x` and `y` values throughout the printing of your document as well, such that adding a link with `Cell` is seamless.

FPDF also has [`Link`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/link.htm) but their documentation reads as such:

> Puts a link on a rectangular area of the page. Text or image links are generally put via Cell(), Write() or Image(), but this method can be useful for instance to define a clickable area inside an image.

Just to clarify, FPDF and HTML differ. Don't use `<a>` for links, use FPDF's `Cell`.

Comment: Thanks, any thoughts on the best way to detect the positions of the matched string within the PDF ? I came across [SetaPDF-Extractor](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-extractor/demos/get-words/) - which looks ideal - but I'm wondering if there might be a way to achieve this without spending on a license...

Comment: Actually that's no good, as it matches whole words only, not phrases.

Comment: The words are sorted in reading order, so you need to add a logic which re-builds the phrases. You may take a look at the "CreateLinkAnnotation.php" example, which is shipped with an evaluation version. It builds links based upon found urls (which are represented by several "word" parts) in a PDF pages content.

Comment: @user3321008 I just want to let you know that we just prepared a ["phrase search" demo](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-extractor/demos/phrase-search/) on our website.